# TypeError: set[i].test is not a function when using 'tfvis.render.linechart'

Tags: tensorflow.js, vega-lite

I tried to use `@tensorflow/tfjs-vis` to draw charts in my React project. But I always get this error, even the example from the main site:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: set[i].test is not a function
```

my code is:

```
const series1 = Array(100).fill(0)
  .map(y => Math.random() * 100 - (Math.random() * 50))
  .map((y, x) => ({ x, y }));

const series2 = Array(100).fill(0)
  .map(y => Math.random() * 100 - (Math.random() * 150))
  .map((y, x) => ({ x, y }));

const series = ['First', 'Second'];
const data = { values: [series1, series2], series }

const surface = { name: 'Line chart', tab: 'Charts' };
tfvis.render.linechart(surface, data);
```

It seems this error happened in `vega-lite`. I have no idea how to fix it, can anyone give me a hint?

I'm using `@tensorflow/tfjs-vis/1.5.1`

I want to use tfjs-vis to draw charts without error.

Comment: fine, I fixed it by downgrading `@tensorflow/tfjs-vis` to `1.1.0`...

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and then mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by downgrading @tensorflow/tfjs-vis to 1.1.0